# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, web SQL

Tags: javascript, web

I had created a database using web SQL that contains 2 columns username and password. To log in the application, I need to check wether the user exist or not. So I wrote this function:

```
html5rocks.webdb.Search = function(user,password){
       var db = html5rocks.webdb.db;
       db.transaction(function(tx){
          tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?",
          [username,password],
          function(rs){
              var verif =false;
                 for(var i=0; i<rs.rows.length; i++)
                     if((rs.rows.item(i).username == username) && (rs.rows.item(i).password == password))
                       verif =true;
                 if(verif == true)
                 {
                        alert("logged in");
                        self.location.href = "login.html";
                  }
                else
                         alert("access denied");
             }, 
          html5rocks.webdb.onSuccess,
          html5rocks.webdb.onError) 
       });
   }
```

But when I run the application I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 
Can any of you tell me what is wrong in this code? 
Thanks

Comment: What it says: `rs.rows` is undefined, therefore cannot be read for a `length` property.

Comment: i believe you sql query is not returning any users that why rs.rows is undefined. Before calculating the length its good to check the object for null or undefined, this way you can save urself from these kind of errors